# File property information (last write time and file size) in explorer out of date by hours over network folder share

Tags: windows, networking, share

An application is running on a windows XP prof machine picking up file from a network share from another windows machine.  It detects that the file has been updated (by date and time or optionally file size) and reads it for any new data.

Most of the time the last write time and file size, seems to be up to date.  Occasionally, this information stops being updated, even though the file is growing (intermittently during the day) with appended content, so that the last write time and file size remain fixed at some arbitrary moment.

This is visible in explorer, where it shows a fixed last write time on the reading machine.

Just opening the file to edit it in notepad, immediately refreshes the file properties, and the other application picks up where it left of.

The file location can't be changed, nor the location of the relevant applications.

Any solutions to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you give more information about the file server (version of windows, whether DFS is involved, etc.?) My guess is that caching is involved but more details are needed to determine if that is so.

Comment: The local machine running the app is WinXP (but SP2).  AFAICT (I'm remoting in to this site), the remote machine is "Windows Server", but what flavor I'm not sure.  I suspect Win2008. 

I have asked the IT Support people to turn off 'cacheing for remote files', but since I'm not trying to store the file locally I imagine this will have no effect (which it hasn't).

I wasn't even aware of MS DFS, so I will followup and see if this is installed.  Are there any issues with DFS and meta file information concurrency?

Comment: Further to that, DFS looks likely as the server name is in a \\xx.domain.com.au\ format.

Comment: I voted to close this as off topic since you are an end user and not the sysadmin. ServerFault isn't really supposed to be for end user support. If your admins can't figure out the problem point them in this direction and make sure they give us details about the server environment.

Comment: I'm not the end user. I'm the developer of the application. If you think is this not a relevant topic, by all means vote away.  The admins think it is related to this now <http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823291> .  I will not be ale to confirm this until we do the update.